# New to ajax... Problems sending email from modal window via php

Tags: php, jquery, ajax

I haven't used a lot of AJAX, and am getting a tad frustrated. 
On my little page, when a user pushes a button, a modal form opens, and prompts for an email, first name, last name, and phone number. I am trying to use ajax to pass this info to a 'sendmessage.php' file, and something is not working.

**HTML:**

```
<!--hidden inline form-->
     <div id="inlineForm">
         <h3>Estimate Request</h3>
         <form id="estimateForm" action="#" method="post" name="estimateForm">
             <label for="formFirstName">First Name:</label>
             <input id="formFirstName" type="text" name="formFirstName"><br />
             <label for="formLastName">Last Name:</label>
             <input id="formLastName" type="text" name="formLastName"><br />
             <label for="formPhone">Phone:</label>
             <input id="formPhone" type="text" name="formPhone" placeholder="(###)###-####"><br />
             <label for="formEmail">Email:</label>
             <input id="formEmail" type="email" name="formEmail" placeholder="example@example.com"><br />
             <button id="formSendButton">Send</button>
        </form>
    </div><!--end of inlineForm div-->
```

**Javascript/AJAX:**

```
     $("#formSendButton").on("click", function(){
        var emailVal = $("#formEmail").val();
        var firstNameVal = $("#formFirstName").val();
        var lastNameVal = $("#formLastName").val();
        var phoneVal = $("#formPhone").val();
        var validEmail = validateEmail(emailVal);
        var validPhone = validatePhone(phoneVal);
        var data = $("#estimateForm").serialize();
          ///////    A bunch of checks to ensure proper values //////
    if(validEmail == true && lastNameVal.length >= 3 && firstNameVal.length >= 3 && validPhone == true){
        $("#estimateForm").css("padding-bottom","23px");
        $("#formSendButton").replaceWith("<em>sending...</em>");
        $.ajax({
            type: 'POST',
            url: 'sendmessage.php',
            data: data,
            success: function(data) {
            if(data == "true") {
                $("#estimateForm").fadeOut("fast", function(){
                $(this).before("<strong>Success!</strong>");
                setTimeout("$.fancybox.close()", 1000);
            });
        }
    }
    });
  }
})
```

and finally, the

**PHP:**

```
<?php
$sendto   = "trevorjames39@gmail.com";
$usermail = $_POST['formEmail'];
$firstName = $_POST['formFirstName'];
$lastName = $_POST['formLastName'];
$phone = $_POST['formPhone'];
$subject  = "Request for Quote";
$headers  = "From: " . strip_tags($usermail) . "\r\n";
$headers .= "Reply-To: ". strip_tags($usermail) . "\r\n";
$headers .= "MIME-Version: 1.0\r\n";
$headers .= "Content-Type: text/html;charset=utf-8 \r\n";

$msg  = "<html><body style='font-family:Arial,sans-serif;'>";
$msg .= "<h2 style='font-weight:bold;border-bottom:1px dotted #ccc;'>Request for Quote</h2>\r\n";
$msg .= "<p><strong>Customer First Name:</strong>-----".$firstName."</p>\r\n";
$msg .= "<p><strong>Customer Last Name:</strong>------".$lastName."</p>\r\n";
$msg .= "<p><strong>Customer Phone Number:</strong>---".$phone."</p>\r\n";
$msg .= "<p><strong>Customer Email address:</strong>--".$usermail."</p>\r\n";
$msg .= "</body></html>";


if(mail($sendto, $subject, $msg, $headers)) {
    echo "true";
} else {
    echo "false";
}

?>
```

I have a functional understanding of the php, but the ajax....

Also, this has been culled mainly from a tutorial I found [here](http://designwoop.com/2012/07/tutorial-coding-a-jquery-popup-modal-contact-form/)

Thanks to anyone who is taking the time to look at this.

Comment: You might want to elaborate a bit. What do you mean by "something isn't working"? Does it send the request to the server? If you're new to JS programming, you should attempt to familiarize yourself with Firebug or the Webkit dev tools.

Comment: Fair enough. I try to use the firebug, but am not 100% sure where to begin on this one. I know that the serialize is working, as I can get that in an alert...

Comment: For example, put a break point on where it actually sends the request. That would be the first thing to check, does it even send it off, or does something else in your code prevent it.

Comment: I did do that... BUt I have to be honest, I'm not sure how to check...

Comment: http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/19417/evan-mrweinerdog

Comment: THank you for the link, will start digging...

Comment: Try the following if you are using jQuery 1.8:  $(document).on("click", "#formSendButton", function()

Comment: FYI, the link is to a chat, I was going to help you out, suggest you join.

Comment: 97% of the time it's the server that's missing the proper email software. If you're running on this on a wamp server from your computer, it's a 99,9% chance that postfix or sendmail is'nt installed or workin properly.

Answer (score 1):

Your default form action is actually kicking in. I think you need to disable that by doing:

```
 onsubmit="return false;"
```

Alternatively you could name your (currently anonymous onclick) function and make your form action

```
action="javascript:yourFunction()"
```

also: I assume that validateEmail and validatePhone are defined somewhere in your code.